# How to connect PowerApps with AzureAD

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am trying to do automate office 365 on Microsoft powerapps and I want to connect it with Azure AD of my organization.so I want to show entire user-list in power apps so I can select the particular user.
The scenario is if the user add in the organization automatically reflect in the drop down List
How can I do this anyone has idea ??

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to document :[Use Azure Active Directory with a custom connector in PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/customapi-azure-resource-manager-tutorial/) . That tutorial demonstrates how to enable authentication in Azure Active Directory, register one of the ARM APIs as a custom connector, then connect to it in PowerApps. I think you could use Azure AD Graph api as resource to get users' information .